# convert if/else to case

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I was wondering if anyone out there is able and willing to assist me.
In my Sql Server stored procedure I have a series of if / else if statements, I would like a little assistance to change it to case...when...then as I feel it would be more efficient and look less messy. 
I am not asking for you to do it for me just a quick example to enable me to get my head around it.

My strored procedure is as follows...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Blog].[ttc_BlogPosts]
@Status varchar(50) = '' ,
@EntryId int = '',
@Title nvarchar(max) = '',
@Added datetime = '',
@Updated datetime = '',
@Message nvarchar(max) = '',
@ImgId int = '',
@ImgUrl nvarchar(max) = ''

AS
BEGIN
     IF(@Status = 'Display')
       begin
            select Id, EntryTitle, Message, ImageUrl, DateAdded, LastEdited
            from Blog.BlogEntry
            order by DateAdded desc
       end

     else if(@Status = 'AddPost')
            begin

                insert into Blog.BlogEntry (EntryTitle, Message, DateAdded, ImageUrl)
                values (@Title, @Message, GETDATE(), @ImgUrl)   
            end
          else if(@Status = 'DisplayPost')
                 begin
                      select EntryTitle, DateAdded, LastEdited, Message, ImageUrl
                      from Blog.BlogEntry
                      where Id = @EntryId
                  end
               else if(@Status = 'UpdatePost')
                      begin
                          update Blog.BlogEntry
                          set EntryTitle = @Title, Message = @Message, LastEdited = GETDATE()
                          where Id = @EntryId
                      end 
                    else if(@Status = 'UpdatePostImage')
                           begin
                           update Blog.BlogEntry
                           set ImageUrl = @ImgUrl, LastEdited = GETDATE(), EntryTitle = @Title, Message = @Message
                           where Id = @EntryId
                        end
                     else if(@Status = 'DeletePost')
                         begin
                              delete from Blog.BlogEntry
                              where Id = @EntryId 
                          end
          END
```

Any help that you guys are willing to offer will be very much appreciated. If any further details are required please do not hesitate to give me a shout ;)

Comment: One thing you can do right now is add indentation in begin end block it will be more readable.

Comment: Simple answer [CASE is not for control-flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174290.aspx)

Comment: I think this is an efficient code as it only call one SP for each specified action. However if you're annoyed of this script, its simply because its not Transaction oriented, you know the BEGIN TRAN -- DO HERE -- END TRAN thing, which is a per stored procedure script . :)

Comment: @kenlacoste If I understand you correctly, I need to add the begin tran after the if(@status = 'display'). Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: @kenlacoste I am afraid your assumption that since it is one sp call it will be more efficient is wrong, sps cache their execution plan, if the first execution end up in an insert statement , a plan will be cached for that statement but if any of the subsequent calls to this procedure tries to execute any other statement sql server will try to force the same execution plan for every subsequent call which will result in horrible performance.

Comment: @kenlacoste adding `BEING TRAN... COMMIT TRAN` will do nothing but just put the statement in its own transaction which doesn't, the performance issue will still persist

Comment: @M.Ali the begin tran... commit tran is a good practice specially of your script would contain lots of inserts and updates, definitely recommendable to be on a separate script, for the efficiency style I took as a point, hehe peace i'm just after this plane simple script produced above, my apologies.

Comment: I agree with you on this part that using explicit transactions is a good practice but its not a solution to the problem we have here :)

Comment: @kenlacoste we don't need transactions here, look at varaible **status** it can be in only one state, so one update/one delete or simply select. There aren't multiple operations here.

Comment: I just voted for lad2025's answer, just to insist the "case" thing in here. :)

Comment: With lad's answer which achieves your (M_Griffiths) case, I just want to remind that your @Sql has NVARCHAR(MAX) thus limited script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**M.Ali**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32182684/5070879) solution with searched CASE to compare readability concerns.

Also added addtional @status validation

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Blog].[ttc_BlogPosts]
     @Status     varchar(50)   = '' ,
     @EntryId    int           = NULL,  
     @Title      nvarchar(max) = '',
     @Added      datetime      = NULL,    
     @Updated    datetime      = NULL,
     @Message    nvarchar(max) = '',
     @ImgId      int           = NULL,
     @ImgUrl     nvarchar(max) = ''
 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- A validate check since your else..if statement don't handle this case
IF (@Status = '' AND @Status NOT IN ('Display', 'DisplayPost', ...))
BEGIN
   RAISERROR('Provide value for @Status variable. Allowed values (Display, ...)',16,1)
   RETURN
END

SELECT @sql = CASE @status 
    WHEN 'Display' THEN
        N'select Id, EntryTitle, Message, ImageUrl, DateAdded, LastEdited
        from Blog.BlogEntry
        order by DateAdded desc'

    WHEN 'AddPost' THEN
        N'insert into Blog.BlogEntry (EntryTitle, Message, DateAdded, ImageUrl)
        values (@Title, @Message, GETDATE(), @ImgUrl)'   

    WHEN 'DisplayPost' THEN
        N'select EntryTitle, DateAdded, LastEdited, Message, ImageUrl
        from Blog.BlogEntry
        where Id = @EntryId'

    WHEN 'UpdatePost' THEN
        N'update Blog.BlogEntry
        set EntryTitle = @Title, Message = @Message, LastEdited = GETDATE()
        where Id = @EntryId'

    WHEN 'UpdatePostImage' THEN
        N'update Blog.BlogEntry
        set ImageUrl = @ImgUrl, LastEdited = GETDATE(), EntryTitle = @Title, Message = @Message
        where Id = @EntryId'

    WHEN 'DeletePost' THEN
        N'delete from Blog.BlogEntry
        where Id = @EntryId'
   END

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql] @Sql 
              ,N'@Status varchar(50),@EntryId int, @Title nvarchar(max), @Added datetime, 
                @Updated datetime, @Message nvarchar(max), @ImgId int, @ImgUrl nvarchar(max)'
              ,@Status 
              ,@EntryId 
              ,@Title 
              ,@Added
              ,@Updated 
              ,@Message 
              ,@ImgId 
              ,@ImgUrl 
END
```

Comment: to insist the "case" for readability, id vote for this, even if it still looks like an IF statement and exec @statement as a comfort zone ;)

Comment: just a quick one, I got the following warning:  Warning 3 SQL71502: Procedure: [Blog].[ttc_BlogPosts] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [Blog].[sp_executesql] or [dbo].[sp_executesql]    Have I entered something incorrectly? I'm afraid I am unsure which is correct? do I add the schema that I'm interacting with? i.e Blog

Comment: @M_Griffiths what warning?

Comment: @M_Griffiths why do you have procedure called that? of course [dbo].[sp_executesql]. I added explicity this to answer.

Comment: what are your parameter values?

Comment: @lad2025 what do you mean by "i added explicity this to answer".       sorry to keep on bugging you and if what I said seems ridiculous in any way

Comment: @M_Griffiths `EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql] @Sql` I edited my answer

Comment: what does [dbo].[sp_executesql] do exactly?

Comment: @M_Griffiths Please [read documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx), second learn about Dynamic SQL, as you see sql variable is text, first based on your status variable it is set to correct path, then it is executed. If you are not sure what are you doing, stay with your solution because using Dynamic SQL when used wrongly can cause SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @M_Griffiths In SSMS you code is highlighted, it knows when to colorize in blue keywords (IF, SELECT, ...). Dynamic  SQL query is all red because it is simple NVARCHAR. Then it is passed to execution. It is like eval() in different languages.

Comment: In simple terms, if you do this in sql [declare @sql nvarchar(500) = N'select ''abc'''; EXEC sp_executesql @sql] it should give you an understanding that sql scripts can be dynamically build to a string and executed.

Comment: @kenlacoste Do you address this to me or M_Griffiths?

Comment: To me in this particular case, script with `IF ELSE` looks more readable than `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Being worried about how your code looks, I'll be more worried about how this code will perform, You will get huge parameter sniffing issues with this procedure, to avoid it you need dynamic sql so that sql server can cache a parameterised execution PLANS for this procedure instead of having one execution plan and trying to execute each query using the same plan.

Also you have some variable values set to invalid values such as Int variables are being set to empty string `''` also datetime variables being set to empty string too please have a look below and this procedure should get you better performance.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Blog].[ttc_BlogPosts]
    @Status     varchar(50)   = '' ,
    @EntryId    int           = NULL,  --< can't set int variable to empty string
    @Title      nvarchar(max) = '',
    @Added      datetime      = NULL,    --< can't set Date/DateTime variable to empty string
    @Updated    datetime      = NULL,
    @Message    nvarchar(max) = '',
    @ImgId      int           = NULL,
    @ImgUrl     nvarchar(max) = ''
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- A validate check since your else..if statement don't handle this case
IF (@Status = '')
 BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Provide value for @Status variable',16,1)
  RETURN
 END

    IF(@Status = 'Display')
        begin
            SET @Sql = N'
            select Id, EntryTitle, Message, ImageUrl, DateAdded, LastEdited
            from Blog.BlogEntry
            order by DateAdded desc'
        end
    else if(@Status = 'AddPost')
        begin
            SET @Sql = N'
            insert into Blog.BlogEntry (EntryTitle, Message, DateAdded, ImageUrl)
            values (@Title, @Message, GETDATE(), @ImgUrl)'   
        end
    else if(@Status = 'DisplayPost')
        begin
            SET @Sql = N'
            select EntryTitle, DateAdded, LastEdited, Message, ImageUrl
            from Blog.BlogEntry
            where Id = @EntryId'
        end
    else if(@Status = 'UpdatePost')
        begin
            SET @Sql = N'
            update Blog.BlogEntry
            set EntryTitle = @Title, Message = @Message, LastEdited = GETDATE()
            where Id = @EntryId'
        end 
    else if(@Status = 'UpdatePostImage')
        begin
            SET @Sql = N'
            update Blog.BlogEntry
            set ImageUrl = @ImgUrl, LastEdited = GETDATE(), EntryTitle = @Title, Message = @Message
            where Id = @EntryId'
        end
    else if(@Status = 'DeletePost')
        begin
            SET @Sql = N'
            delete from Blog.BlogEntry
            where Id = @EntryId'
        end

Exec sp_executesql @Sql 
                  ,N'@Status varchar(50),@EntryId int, @Title nvarchar(max), @Added datetime, 
                    @Updated datetime, @Message nvarchar(max), @ImgId int, @ImgUrl nvarchar(max)'
                  ,@Status 
                  ,@EntryId 
                  ,@Title 
                  ,@Added
                  ,@Updated 
                  ,@Message 
                  ,@ImgId 
                  ,@ImgUrl 
END
```

Comment: You could generate this @sql using `SELECT @sql = CASE @Status WHEN 'Display' ...` it will be a lot cleaner way.

Comment: @lad2025 since readability is also a concern adding this much of code lines in a CASE statement will make it really difficult to read. CASE statement is good when you are only dealing with optional parameters. Just other day I gave an answer using case statement here have look [`Optional Parameters`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108903/dynamic-filters-in-sql-server/108908#108908)

Comment: So simply you wrap his solution to Dynamic SQL making it less readable.

Comment: @lad2025 YES!!! adding all of these insert, delete and update statements in a case statement will make it less readable, maybe you have some super eyesight I don't.

Comment: I don't have eagle eye, look and compare to your solution and tell I am wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182299/convert-if-else-to-case/32183167#32183167

Answer (score 0):

So, in the spirit of

> *"just a quick example to enable me to get my head around it..."*

You could do dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = CASE
                  WHEN @Status = 'Display' THEN @SQL = 'select Id, EntryTitle, Message, ImageUrl, DateAdded, LastEdited from Blog.BlogEntry    order by DateAdded desc'
                  WHEN @Status = 'DisplayPost' THEN ...
                  WHEN @Status = 'UpdatePost' THEN ...
                  WHEN @Status = 'UpdatePostImage' THEN ...
                  WHEN @Status = 'DeletePost' THEN ...
              END

EXEC (@SQL)
```

The only catch you're going to run into is you'll need to concatenate your variables into your statements like the following

```
THEN @SQL = 'update Blog.BlogEntry set EntryTitle =''' + @Title + ''', Message =''' + @Message + ''', LastEdited = ''' + GETDATE() + ''' where Id = ''' @EntryId
```

Comment: Great answer, open him to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, IF/ELSE serves a completely different function from CASE/WHEN, and the two are rarely interchangeable.

IF/ELSE can be used to control flow:

```
IF This
  DO THAT
ELSE
  DO Something else
```

CASE/WHEN returns a single value, and cannot control flow.

```
SET @MyValue = CASE 
  WHEN [Color] = 'Red' THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

Your code is not a good candidate for CASE/WHEN since you are using the IF/ELSE to control flow.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. That's simple transformation of IF .. ELSE  into CASE.. ELSE ... END

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Blog].[ttc_BlogPosts]
@Status varchar(50) = '' ,
@EntryId int = '',
@Title nvarchar(max) = '',
@Added datetime = '',
@Updated datetime = '',
@Message nvarchar(max) = '',
@ImgId int = '',
@ImgUrl nvarchar(max) = ''

AS
BEGIN
     CASE WHEN(@Status = 'Display')
        THEN
            select Id, EntryTitle, Message, ImageUrl, DateAdded, LastEdited
            from Blog.BlogEntry
            order by DateAdded desc


        ELSE (CASE WHEN(@Status = 'AddPost')
              THEN

                insert into Blog.BlogEntry (EntryTitle, Message, DateAdded, ImageUrl)
                values (@Title, @Message, GETDATE(), @ImgUrl)   

              ELSE (CASE WHEN(@Status = 'DisplayPost')
                     THEN
                          select EntryTitle, DateAdded, LastEdited, Message, ImageUrl
                          from Blog.BlogEntry
                          where Id = @EntryId

                   ELSE (CASE WHEN(@Status = 'UpdatePost')
                          THEN
                              update Blog.BlogEntry
                              set EntryTitle = @Title, Message = @Message, LastEdited = GETDATE()
                              where Id = @EntryId

                        ELSE (CASE WHEN(@Status = 'UpdatePostImage')
                               THEN
                               update Blog.BlogEntry
                               set ImageUrl = @ImgUrl, LastEdited = GETDATE(), EntryTitle = @Title, Message = @Message
                               where Id = @EntryId

                               ELSE (CASE WHEN(@Status = 'DeletePost')
                                 THEN
                                      delete from Blog.BlogEntry
                                      where Id = @EntryId 
                                  END)
                               END)
                         END)
                     END)
                END)
            END
END
```